# Length of a rectangle

Tags: math, aspect-ratio

Given 4 random points, could I find the length of each side of the quadrilateral? Could I do the same for a triangle?

Basically, I am trying to find the aspect ratio of the geometric shape.

Comment: "given 4 random points, can I find the length of each side of the quadrilateral?" The answer is Yes. But if you want help with your programming problem, please let us know what your input looks like, what language you are working with and include your code/attempts so far...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.  It might do better on [math.se]

Comment: You could use the distance formula to find the length of each side.  That's all you need.

Comment: I don't think finding the lengths of the sides of a quadrilateral can help you find its aspect ratio, in general. For example, if you have sides 1,1,1, and 1, the quadrilateral might be a tall, thin diamond, or a short, wide diamond. The two would have wildly different aspect ratios.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can find the length of each side of the quadrilateral.
But First you need to identify each side using the point given.

For example i have four points A(x1,y1), B(x2,y2), C(x3,y3), D(x4,y4).

Now you have to identify the rectangle it may be ABCD or ADCB or BDCA or something else.
if we consider ABCD then you can find the length by

`AB =((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)^1/2`

In this way you can identify the length of each side.